# Assembler & C - translate C's code to assembler

Tags: assembly, x86

I read a book that write the next program in C, and convet the call of this function to assembler code:

```
int *p;    /* pointer to integer */
int foo (int n, int *q) {}
/* function get int and pointer to int, returns int */
/* Now, let's call the function: */    
*p = foo (*p, p);
```

It convert to:

```
MOV EBX, [P]
PUSH EBX
PUSH DWORD [EBX]
CALL foo
MOV EBX, [P]
MOV [EBX], EAX
ADD ESP, 8
```

I didn't understood why it is correct, as I understood it the code should looks like this:

```
MOV EBX, P   ;; **CHANGE**
PUSH EBX
PUSH DWORD [EBX]
CALL foo
MOV EBX, P ;; **CHANGE**
MOV [EBX], EAX
ADD ESP, 8
```

and that because P is a pointer. If we do `MOV EBX, [P]`, as the book suggest, we got the integer number (Not the adress), and then if we do `PUSH DWORD [EBX]`, we got illigal instruction.

Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`P` is a label, which equates to the address of a variable (your pointer variable).  `[P]` would be the value at that address, which is the pointer.

Note, though, some assemblers do things a bit differently.  NASM and its derivatives are pretty strict about brackets and such.  MASM, not so much; there are times it will let you treat a label almost as if it were a variable in its own right.

Comment: How you understand that P is a label? It's write that `int *p; /* pointer to integer */`. Can you extend your answer? Thanks

Comment: @Adam: `P` is a label because assembly language doesn't really have "variables".  There's registers, and there's memory; either one can hold a value.  If you use memory, though, you need to know where to store the value.  Which means, you need either an offset from the stack pointer (for local variables), a label (for static/global ones), or an absolute address (if you're feeling froggy).

Comment: If I remember right, masm would translate `mov ebx, p` as `mov ebx, [p]` - if you wanted the address of `p` you would have to write `mov ebx, offset p`

Answer (score 1):

P is assumed to be inside of a function like this:

```
void foo(){
  int *p;    /* pointer to integer */
  int foo (int n, int *q) {}
  /* function get int and pointer to int, returns int */

  *p = foo (*p, p);
}
```

In this case, P will be the "location of the variable" or a "label" in assembly terms. Because P will usually be allocated on the stack int his case, this means that when you do `*p=10;` You're actually doing something like this:

```
mov EBX,[p] ;; get the value of the p variable (a pointer)
mov [EBX],10 ;; dereference the value of p and assign it to 10
```